# Two opening clauses, two commas?

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, commas

> Additonally, as they increase in independence, it will make them less anxious about seperation.

Can I omit one comma and which one? It just looks and sounds wrong.

Is it better to keep both?

Comment: It's correct as it stands
 (https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/)

Comment: You need to explain why you think it might be wrong. You shouldn't use "looks and sounds wrong" as a reason.